# evaluation of $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2\pi^{2}z^{2}n^{2}}$ for large z

Tags: sequences-and-series, theta-functions, euler-maclaurin

I want to evaluate the following

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2\pi^{2}z^{2}n^{2}}
\end{equation}
 I know for $z\ll 1$  we can use Euler-Maclaurin formula but in my case z is quite large ($z\gg 1$). can anyone give me a hint of how can I evaluate this or at least be able to approximate it? or even an almost tight upper bound?

Comment: If $z$ is large, the terms with $n\neq 0$ are *very* small.

Comment: @metamorphy yes but how does this help?

Comment: I just don't understand what kind of approximation do you need. The series itself is a very good one ;) (BTW, how do you use E.M. for small $z$? It is done much better by [modular transformations of theta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_identities).)

Comment: As @metamorphy points out, the natural approximation is just the first terms of the series: $S \approx  1 +2[\exp{(-2 \pi^2 z^2) } + \exp{(-2 \pi^2 z^2 4)} + \cdots]$

Comment: @metamorphy in fact I used Mathematica to evaluate this sum for (z=2 as an example) and I found the answer to be 1.  I just need some sort of analytical approximation to confirm that value of Mathematica

Comment: @leonbloy yes but how do you know the rest of the series won't sum to a non-zero value? since it has infinite terms we need to somehow show that for $n\neq0$ it won't be summed up to a non-zero value

Comment: @metamorphy for z<<1 look at chapter 9 of concrete mathematics book by  Donald Knuth, Oren Patashnik, and Ronald Graham

Comment: It is just an *estimation* there. The link given above provides an *exact* result (which is usually proven using [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula)) [Upd. The exercise 59 there is about this same thing].

Comment: @metamorphy I'm not really familiar with the modular transformation do you think it is possible to explain it a bit more? or suggesting some papers?

Comment: `N[Sum[Exp[-2 Pi^2 n^2 2^2], {n, -1, 1}], 40] == 1.000000000000000000000000000000000102450`.

Comment: @somos I'm aware of this result but this is not what I'm looking for, I'm looking for a more analytical way than to just write down code, imagine you didn't have any access to the computer there must be an approximation to this sum which results in Mathematica to give this value, I am more interested in that approximation.

Comment: The sum cannot be 1 as the term for $n=0$ evaluates to 1. All other terms are strictly positive.

Comment: @GautamShenoy yes but it is "approximately" 1 since other terms are exponentially small, in fact, that was the reason I asked the question this is the concerns here since other terms might lead to a large number, however, given the answer Somos provide we can say for a large value of z the approximation is very close to 1

Comment: Just leave off the $1$ term and you'll have better precision.  A floating point number tracks the exponent in scientific notation, but if you have a $1$ term at the beginning this exponent will be $0$, and you won't have as many correct digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the null theta funtion
$$ f(q) := \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2} = 1 +
 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} q^{n^2} \tag{1} $$
where $\,|q|<1\,$ is needed for convergence. Assume that further
$\,0<q<1.\,$ This implies that truncating the infinite sum will
result in increasing lower bounds such as 
$$ 1 < 1 + 2q < 1 + 2q + 2q^4 < \cdots < f(q). \tag{2} $$
However, comparing it to a geometric series gives an upper bound
$$ f(q) < 1 + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^n = 1 + \frac{2q}{1-q} = \frac{1+q}{1-q} \tag{3} $$
although better upper bounds exist. For example,
$$ f(q) < 1 + 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{3n+1} = 1+2q+\frac{2q^4}{1-q^3} \tag{3} $$ and so on. Thus,
$$ f(q) \!<\! \cdots \!<\! 1 \!+\! 2q \!+\! 2q^4 \!+\! 
\frac{2q^9}{1\!-\!q^5} \!<\! 1 \!+\! 2q \!+\! \frac{2q^4}{1\!-\!q^3} \!<\! 1 \!+\! \frac{2q}{1\!-\!q}. \tag{4} $$